# Enable 256 colors for cygwin under mintty?

Tags: terminal, cygwin, mintty

I am using cygwin via mintty, which is the default. I installed ncurses. I then run these commands to see what my color pallet is for this terminal session:

```
$ tput colors
8
```

I have googled but so far nothing. How can I get a nice 256 color palette for my mintty cygwin terminal instead of the default (lame) 8 colors?

Comment: If you use mintty, you can apparently set the terminal type to xterm-256...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try `export TERM=xterm-256color` or equivalent. You can add that to the appropriate dotfile if you want it to be persistent. You can use a 256-color demo script like [this](https://raw.github.com/incitat/eran-dotfiles/master/bin/terminalcolors.py) to verify functionality.

Comment: This worked for me too. But I can't get it to work over SSH to Windows from my Mac iTerm2. It does work with the same settings when I SSH to an Ubuntu box.

Comment: A "dotfile" being any file starting with a dot, I would at least advise to NOT set TERM variable in dotfiles that are related to your shell, as opposed to dotfiles related to your terminal emulator program. This is because a shell may be used with multiple terminal emulators, and setting TERM there is obviously a misplacement mistake, an all too common one I am afraid. If you are going to override TERM value, the proper place to do so is not in a shell dotfile, but a terminal emulator dotfile, if there is one,  in this case something like `~/.minttyrc`. I hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: So if in mintty I have TERM set to xterm-256color and I run that script and I only get some very slow output of solid black lines, what does that mean I should do about fixing it? `tput colors` tells me `256`.

Answer (score 31):

Right-click in mintty, then in `Options...`->`Terminal`, change type to `xterm-256color`, click `OK`, close mintty and re-launch it.

Comment: It's also `Term=xterm-256color` in .minttyrc. Anyway this should be the right answer for Cygwin mintty